# Update age based on dob in a collection in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I have 1000 Documents in one of the collection.

> { "_id": ObjectId("56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76"), "parseId":
>   "TdKxj9FFPY", "phone": "6643545645", "dob": "15-06-87", "age": 121
>   "createdAt": ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "updatedAt":
>   ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "__v": 0 }
>
> { "_id":ObjectId("56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76"), "parseId": "TdKxj9FFPY",
>   "phone": "9847523654", "dob": "15-06-93", "age": 100 "createdAt":
>   ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "updatedAt":
>   ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "__v": 0 }
>
> { "_id":ObjectId("56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76"), "parseId": "TdKxj9FFPY",
>   "phone": "4564646646", "dob": "15-06-43", "age": 152 "createdAt":
>   ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "updatedAt":
>   ISODate("2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z"), "__v": 0 }
>
> ...................
>
> ...................

But some of the values of **age** are wrong.The Values of **dob** are right.So i need to update the values of age based on the dob in a single query manually?

Comment: are you asking how to do this with a mysql query, through just json manipulation (nosql), or by some other means where you're accessing this data?

Comment: Why do you store the same information twice? Have one canonical representation (DoB, probably in a more sensible format than `DD-MM-YY`) and calculate the age based on that when necessary.

Comment: @Dreamlines :I want to upadte the collection using terminal(nosql)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Age values are wrong.But dob is correct.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, my point is that you should just *delete the age from the database*, and probably update the DoB to a format you can sensibly order by. Otherwise you have to update your database (at least) daily to keep current ages up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.I just export the collection in to a json file and updated all the documents by using js function and import the collections in to the db.

**html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="save">save</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
var exportData;
$.getJSON("input.json", function(data) {
    exportData = data;
    exportData.forEach(function(item, index) {
        // console.log('item dob', item.dob);
        var dobInfo = item.dob.split('-');
        var dd = dobInfo[0];
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        var mm = dobInfo[1];
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }
        var yy = dobInfo[2];
        yy = (yy < 17) ? '20' + yy : '19' + yy;
        // console.log('dd', dd);
        // console.log('mm', mm);
        // console.log('yy', yy);
        var newdate = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yy;
        // console.log('newdate',newdate);
        console.log('index[' + index + ']', item.dob);
        var age = getAge(newdate);
        console.log('age--->', age);
        exportData[index].age = age;
    });
});
document.getElementById('save').onclick = function() {
    var textToSave = JSON.stringify(exportData),
        filename = 'output.json',
        blob = new Blob([textToSave], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        });

    saveAs(blob, filename);
}
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: my bad about the first one.

Export your data to a JSON and run it through this and reimport it. Your only dependency is fs and momentjs.

```
var moment = require('moment'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    json = [
        { "_id":"56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76", "parseId": "TdKxj9FFPY", "phone": "6643545645", "dob": "15-06-87", "age": 121, "createdAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "updatedAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "__v": 0 },
        { "_id":"56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76", "parseId": "TdKxj9FFPY", "phone": "9847523654", "dob": "15-06-93", "age": 100, "createdAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "updatedAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "__v": 0 },
        { "_id":"56d97671f6ad671b7d1c3d76", "parseId": "TdKxj9FFPY", "phone": "4564646646", "dob": "15-06-43", "age": 152, "createdAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "updatedAt": "2016-03-01T16:39:00.947Z", "__v": 0 }
    ];

Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
    age = moment().diff(moment(json[key].dob,"DD/MM/YY"),'years');

    //
    //dates before 1970 are negative
    //
    if (parseInt(age) < 0) {
        age += 100;
    }

    json[key].age = age;
});

fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(json), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('compeleted');
});
```

age outputs = [29, 23, 74];

Comment: you're completely right. I'll update this in a second. tired and not thinking